# Inconsistent Behavior in WKNavigationDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app that mainly consist of a WKWebView.
I monitor it's navigation status using the WKNavigationDelegate protocol.

I create my viewController as a WKNavigationDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    ...
```

I load the request on the webview like so:

```
let gotoUrl = ... as? String
if let url = URL(string: gotoUrl) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)            
}
```

And then the delegate methods:

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Successfully loaded")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Did commit navigation")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Start Provisional navigation")
    }

    func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView:WKWebView) {
        print("request failed")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("request failed")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!, withError: Error) {
        print("request failed")
    }
```

This works fine for my webapps initial url: **https://example.com/app/**
Then the delegate methods are called.

When the app is opened from a notification I want to direct the webview to a specific part of the webapp. 
However when i load an url that load a specific part of the webapp: 
**https://example.com/app/#/secure/content/alarm-base/alarm-list//alarm-detail/1381122**
The delegate methods are not called, although the webview loads the url successfully. 
The delegate methods are also called if I load the specific url directly on startup. 
The web appication is written in AngularJS.

I would like for the delegate handlers to trigger for every request I load from the code. 
Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: It seems you can force this by adding

```
webView.load(request)
webView.stopLoading()
webView.reload()
```

It is clunky, bit it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on, but it is possible to force it to use the delegate by adding the following code when doing the request:

```
webView.load(request) 
webView.stopLoading() 
webView.reload()
```

It is clunky, but it solves the problem for me.